# World nodes keyframes does not work

Tags: rendering, animation, light, keyframes

Keyframing the node values works in the viewport but not in the final render (Eevee). I want to make World lighting continually darker. Blender only keeps the initial "Start frame" value throughout the animation. I tried multiple Blender versions. Any suggestions? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you add a *Value Node* to your graph, you can type `#frame` in the value field which will make the value correspond with the current frame as the frame changes. You could combine this with math nodes to set the timing and the direction (toward beginning or toward end) of the fade that you want. This example fades the background from bright white (At frame 0) to full black (at frame 250):

[image: FrameFade]

Comment: Thanks, but apparently some of the world keyframes do not work in the final render in 2.93 onwards. 2.91 and 2.92 work fine. Hopefully, it'll be fixed soon since 2.92 does not have a new sick DOF.